# Database.Query give wrong result

Tags: apex, java

Check these Screen Shots
See the Query here which is wrong:
[image]

See the result here
[image]

help me out to resolve the issue.
Thanks in Advance,

Comment: I think query is correct. What wrong according to you?

Comment: here is good explanation about things, that bothers you - http://www.crmsalesforcetraining.com/alias-notations-in-soql-basic-soql-statements/

Comment: `eeretsavd` just an alias. Your query is correct.

Comment: Now I understand the concept of alias.Thanks to all.

Answer (score 3):

The query is fine, you've given the table Lead an alias 'eeretsavd'. This means you can use that name later on in the query if you want to name columns from that table. See page 2 of chapter 1 (actually page 6 of the PDF) of [the documentation](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_soql_sosl.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You can dramastically simplify your code, and also as people have mentioned you are currently setting 'eeretsavd' as an alias.

This is what your code should look like, replacing *FIELD NAME* with that actual field name for the field containing 'eeretsavd'.

```
List<Lead> leads = [SELECT Id, Name from Lead WHERE *FIELD NAME* = 'eeretsavd'];
System.Debug('######' + leads.size());
```